# Dynamic Loader optimisation in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I was [watching some WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/) that discussed ways to profile and optimize the load time of various applications.  (2016/2015)  This mainly involves digging deep into DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS

On of the kernel optimizations was based on the quantity of libraries used, and mapping them to the virtual address space.

When I compile a Xamarin iOS application, what is the correlation of C# based libraries and this corresponding iOS library?

Since I’m considering using many different components, and other DLLs, if there is a 1:1 mapping from DLL to Xamarin produced iOS library, then I’ll incur a very long non-optimized DYLD load time.

Is it possible to compile all dependencies into a single DLL, to optimize iOS load time? Or are there other optimizations available?